# Not able to edit Global Publisher Layout

Tags: salesforce1-app, publisher

When I click on edit link available at Global Publisher Layout, it throws an error as attached. Please help.

[image]

Comment: Please clear the browser cache to see if it helps

Comment: That sounds like a support case to me. If you're in a customer org or sandbox, please raise that with your support channel. If this is a DE org, please post to the developer forums at developer.salesforce.com/forums. Dev support regularly monitor that channel for bugs and cases.

Comment: I cleared the browser and still the same error is coming. This error is coming in my developer org.